# blender wont render using the correct enigne

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, rigid-body-simulation

So, I'm a complete newbie at blender started just a few days ago and I can't for the life of me figure this out. I will set the render engine to cycles but whenever I hit f12 it just renders with Eevee and what's worse is that it's not even the correct lighting or anything if I just view it is using Eevee.

this is what it looks like in the viewport using Eevee or cycles
[image]
[image]

and this is what it looks like when I render
[image]

I'm also doing this with rigid body world on if that changes anything

Comment: Do you have a supported graphics card and if so is it enabled under Preferences > System? - The Device setting (GPU compute) below Render in your Scene options appears to be disabled.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JohnEason (sorry it took a long time for me to look at this) I did what you said and set the cycles render device in preferences to CUDA and used my graphics card which is an RTX 2070 so I believe it's supported. Now it's not greyed out like before but it's still rendering the same image it was before.                                                                                      Something else to note is that no matter what i do the rendered image won't change. i deleted the whole scene but when i went to render it was the same exact image as before.

Comment: I think someone here is going to have to look at your Blend file (uploaded to https://pasteall.org/blend/ ) to see what's going on.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/c436a0fc00d6486683a04515b7410e49 this is the file, I had to delete some blocks to get it less than 24MB